# Filter an IQueryable with case insensitive.

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

```
IQueryable<MyModel> myList = GetListMyModel().AsQueryable();
myList = myList.Where(m => m.Name.Contains('John'));
```

I want to return everything with Name = 'John' or 'john' or 'JOHN' (case-insensitive)

Comment: `'John'` is going to throw an error because apostrophes are for character literals. You'll want to use `"John"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all into lower case filter like

```
IQueryable<MyModel> myList = GetListMyModel().AsQueryable();
myList = myList.Where(m => m.Name.ToLower().Contains("John".ToLower());
```

Or use

```
IQueryable<MyModel> myList = GetListMyModel().AsQueryable();
myList = myList.Where(m => m.Name.IndexOf("John",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = myList.Where(m => m.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("John".ToLowerInvariant()));
```

Comment: unless you are dealing with e.g. EntityFramework, then this approach would not succeed, only as long as you are dealing with Linq2Objects

Comment: @Abion47: Yepp, silly copy paste error ;) edit on the go :)

Comment: @J C Sharper: Please clarify the actual source beneath GetListMyModel, as the "duplicate-flag" on this question might be wrong

Comment: I doubt it. The crux of this question does seem to stem from a case-insensitive `Contains` check, which would make the dupe flag accurate.